# Which CPU should I choose ? 10700K, Ryzen 3900X or 11700K?

Tags: graphics-cards, processor, gaming, performance

The RTX 3080 arriving it seems in September, I started to build my new rig.

I selected 3 processors for this but I'm still really hesitant, I actually need help in choosing:

1. 10700K:

   **Pros**: Currently one of the most efficient processors for gaming, it outperforms the Ryzen 3900X, beaten by the 10900K but it's not worth it. Cheaper than the Ryzen.

   **Cons**: About everything else: low in multi threading, 14nm, no overclocking except Z card, does not natively support RAM> 2933, PCIe 3.0
2. Ryzen 3.9:

   **Pros**: excellent in multi-threading (FS 2020?), Cost per thread much lower than Intel, PCIe 4.0, Tdp 105W, 7nm

   **Cons**: slightly less performing than the Intel on gaming and it may get worst with the RTX 3080, can't really be overclocked over 100Mhz, can lose MT performance once overclocked
3. 11700K

   **Pros**: Pcie 4.0, 10nm

   **Cons**: not yet released, could be announced announced on September 2, price to come?

I have a small concern about the Pcie 4.0: I will have an RTX 3080, a sound card (usually used in optics but sometimes in analog, that's why I keep it), an Areca card for the RAID, and an Asus 10Gpbs Ethernet card (which I will keep because the signal is better than via the motherboard).

I mainly use gaming, even if I will be using flight simulator 2020, I work remotely and study with scientific Python, and sometimes uses Matlab but not enough to justify my choice on this.

It clearly seems to me that the best processor is the Ryzen, but I'm not sure if it's the best **for me**. It would cost me $ 150 more with lower in-game performance, and I don't think I will win on the motherboard (an MSI Z490 e gaming wifi costs me $ 270).

Do you think the PCIe ports will be bottle-necked? If not, which processor would you take in my place?

This computer will last for 5 years, this is always what I do: build a balanced computer, keep it for 5 years, then replace it and sell the rig while it's still useful for gaming even when it's obsolete, I went from gtx580 to gtx1080 and now rtx3080. So this is a consideration to keep in mind, I want no bottle-neck and all my components to be balanced together.

Note: the 10600K is not in the list because the difference is barely $ 40.

Comment: First your sound card and 10g network card will see no benefit from pcie 4.  The Areca card will only benefit if it also supports pcie 4.0, and give how new the pcie 4 standard is I doubt it is.  So if the RTX 3080 support 4.0 then it will benefit at varying levels if your generating enough GPU bandwidth.  Most games don't even use all the bandwidth in pcie 3.0 x16 slots.

Comment: How many pcie lanes is your Areca card x1,2,4,8,16?

Comment: If you're waiting for Ampere why not also wait for Zen 3 and Tiger Lake?

Comment: My Areca card definitely will NOT benefit PCIe 4.0, it is too old. However I could upgrade but that's really not necessary since I do not even have issues for 4k streaming.
So only the RTX would benefit from it.
I will not wait for Zen 3 and Tiger Lake because I do not feel the need to wait and pay more (those proc will be > what I pay now) unless it is absolutely necessary to correctly exploit my new rig. I could still resell the proc in 2 years and buy another on the same socket.